# Flask blueprint static directory does not work?

Tags: python, flask

[According to the Flask readme](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#static-files), blueprint static files are accessible at `blueprintname/static`. But for some reason, it doesn't work.

My blueprint is like this:

- `app/frontend/views.py` :

  ```
  frontend = Blueprint('frontend', __name__, 
                       template_folder='templates',
                       static_folder='static')

  @frontend.route('/') etc...
  ```
- `app/frontend/js/app.js` : my javascript
- Blueprint registered in Flask app (routes work and everything)

When I go to `abc.com/frontend/static/js/app.js`, it just gives a 404.

When I follow the Flask readme to get my static files:

```
<script src="{{url_for('frontend.static', filename='js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

The output is

```
<script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
```

Which doesn't work either. There's nothing in my root `app/static/` folder.

I can't access any static files in my blueprint! Flask read me says that it should work!

> ```
> admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__, static_folder='static')
> ```
>
> By default the rightmost part of the path is where it is exposed on the web. Because the folder is called static here it will be available at the location of the blueprint + /static. Say the blueprint is registered for /admin the static folder will be at /admin/static.

Comment: How did you register your Blueprint with the app?

Comment: Also worth noting, you will need to have your JS file at `app/frontend/static/js/app.js` rather than `app/frontend/js/app.js` (note the inclusion of a `static` folder in your file path).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I include an argument to the static_url_path parameter to ensure that the Blueprint's static path doesn't conflict with the static path of the main app.

e.g:

```
admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__, static_folder='static', static_url_path='/static/admin')
```

Comment: I actually had to do static_url_path='/admin/static' instead of /static/admin

Comment: Ty 4 `static_url_path`.  For main _static_: `static_url_path='../static/'`

Answer (score 34):

You probably registered your Blueprint to sit at the root of your site:

```
app.register_blueprint(core, url_prefix='')
```

but the `static` view in the Blueprint is no different from all your other Blueprint views; it uses that `url_prefix` value to make the URL unique.

The *core* `static` view is *also* active, so you now have two routes that want to handle `/static/` URLs. So if you are registering your Blueprint without a URL prefix, you have to give one of these two a unique path.

Either give the Blueprint a custom `static_url_path` value, or the core Flask `app`.

Comment: Thanks, this was unclear in the read me. Thinking of static as just another routed URL makes sense. It's just problematic because the default behavior of both the Blueprint and the core Flask app are to use `/static/`.

Answer (score 16):

It worked for me by initializing blueprint like this:

```
configuration = Blueprint('configuration', __name__, template_folder='templates',static_folder='static')
```

Then referencing to static file like this

```
href="{{ url_for('.static', filename='css/base.css') }}"
```

There is a dot before static in href.

Comment: works with charm, but i am still confused with Flask. Can you suggest a good read?

Answer (score 6):

I am using Flask blueprints.

My web app [Attendance Manager](https://github.com/HarshKapadia2/attendance_management/tree/v2) has three types of users, admin, teacher and student.

Here is how a part of the file structure looks:

```
+---app.py
|
|
+---student
|   |   student.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   +---static
|   |   +---css
|   |   |       login-page.css
|   |   |       signup-page.css
|   |   |       
|   |   \---js
|   |           firebaseConfig.js
|   |           
|   +---templates
|   |       base.html
|   |       student-login-page.html
|   |       student-signup-page.html
```

app.py:

```
app.register_blueprint(student, url_prefix='/student')
```

student.py:

```
student = Blueprint('student', __name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='templates')
```

student-login-page.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('student.static', filename='css/login-page.css') }}">
```

Adding 'the_name_of_the_blueprint.static' to the first parameter of url_for() in the student-login-page.html (or wherever you are linking your css) helped me resolve the problem.

Found the solution [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/#static-files), in the official docs.

[This](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/348) GitHub issue or [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/61niyi/af_static_folder_with_blueprints/) Reddit post might help you if this did not resolve your problem.

All the best!

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late, but none of the previous answers did really help me in achieving what I needed. I found out that I needed to do a bit of "tricks" to make the module's static folder work as I intended. 
My application is composed of several modules, but for now just pretend we had "application" as the main application folder and "locations" as the module's folder where a local "static" directory is placed (where we need to load static files for this module). The following is what I did:

1. In the main application's `__init__py` file I added `url_prefix='/'` to my Blueprint's definition
2. In my module's `routes.py` file I used both static parameters: `static_folder='static'` and `'static_url_path='/locations/static'` to declare the Blueprint
3. In the html template (which extends a template in the main application's folder), I used the following to retrieve the path to the static css file: `{{url_for('locations_bp.static', filename='css/style.css')}}` (`locations_bp` is my Bluprint's name for "locations" module)

This way, the css file is loaded as `/locations/static/css/style.css` and this is exactly what I wanted to achieve: above all, the url_prefix I used allows me to avoid having a prefix on all my module's routes

Answer (score 0):

This problem has happened to me for several times. Once I add `static_url_path` and it worked, then it just suddenly got broken some day. The final solution is

```
url_prefix='/admin'
```

Don't know why but `url_prefix=''` or `url_prefix='/'` do not work for me.