# Static folder in Flask App engine project

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am unable to reference the css in my html. I am using Blueprints.

Here is a screenshot of my folder structure in pycharm.

[image]

My app.yaml has the following

```
- url: .*  # This regex directs all routes to main.app
  script: main.app
```

Blueprint definition

```
admin_home_routes = Blueprint("admin", __name__, template_folder="../templates", static_folder="../static")
```

HTML from where I call the css is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('admin.static',filename='css/admin.css') }}" type="text/css"/>
```

The end result is that I am unable to load the css.

The URL produced is :-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/admin.css" type="text/css">
```

I want the css to be modular, but latter on I might also choose to minify and compress various css files.

Comment: What URL is produced?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/css/admin.css">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask blueprint static directory does not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152840/flask-blueprint-static-directory-does-not-work)